# trouble getting cv.transform to work

Tags: python, opencv, numpy, affinetransform

I'd like to use the same affine matrix M on some individual (x,y) points as I use on images with cv2.warpAffine. It seems cv2.transform is the way to go .  When I try send an Nx2 matrix of points I get negged (

```
   src = np.array([
        [x1,y1],[x2,y2],[x3,y3],[x4,y4]],  dtype = "float32")
    print('source shape '+str(src.shape))
    dst=cv2.transform(src,M)

cv2.error: /home/jeremy/sw/opencv-3.1.0/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:1947: error: (-215) scn == m.cols || scn + 1 == m.cols in function transform
```

I can get the transform I want just using numpy arithmetic :

```
    dst = np.dot(src,M[:,0:2]) +M[:,2]
    print('dest:{}'.format(dst))
```

But would like to understand whats going on .  The docs say that cv2.transform wants a number of channels equal to number of columns in M  but I'm not clear what the channels would be - maybe an 'x' channel and 'y' channel, but then would would the third be, and what would the different rows signify?

Comment: Often times when OpenCV expects points they like them in the form `np.array([ [[x1, y1]], [[x2, y2]], ... ])`. They usually want that for point transformations---a single column or row vector with length as the number of points and channels equivalent to the number of coordinates. The third coordinate could be a coordinate in a third dimension---transformation matrices aren't just for 2D transformations after all.

Comment: thanks that did the trick , i had the dimension order backwards mentally, c*h*w instead of h*w*c, too much caffe

Comment: not related to the question itself, but the numpy equivalent code will run fine but is not the correct transformation that you want. the numpy euivalent of cv2.transform would be `(np.dot(M[:,:2], a.T)+M[:,2].reshape(2,1)).T`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

OpenCV on Python often wants points in the form

```
np.array([ [[x1, y1]], ..., [[xn, yn]] ])
```

This is not clear in the [documentation for `cv2.transform()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cv2.transform#transform) but is more clear in the documentation for other functions that use points, like [`cv2.perspectiveTransform()`](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html?highlight=cv2.transform#perspectivetransform) where they mention coordinates to be on separate channels:

> **src** – input two-channel or three-channel floating-point array

Transforms can also be used in 3D (using a `4x4` perspective transformation matrix) so that would explain the ability to use two- *or* three-channel arrays in `cv2.transform()`.

Comment: For the use case mentioned above (2D transform of an Nx2 matrix of points), one shorthand is `dst = cv2.transform( np.array([src]),M)[0]`

Comment: Slightly better: `cv2.transform(src[None, ...], M)[0]`. This creates a view to the `src` array, while `np.array([src])` creates an additional array which duplicates the memory and takes around 10x longer.

Answer (score 1):

The channel is the last dimension of the source array. Let's read the docs of cv2.transform() at the beginning.[image]

---

**To the question**:

Because the function transforms each element from the parameter `src`, the dimension of `src` is required to be bigger than 2.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

rotation_mat = np.array([[0.8660254, 0.5, -216.41978046], [-0.5, 0.8660254, 264.31038357]]) # 2x3

rotate_box = np.array([[410, 495], [756, 295], [956, 642], [610, 842]]) # 2x2
result_box = cv2.transform(rotate_box, rotation_mat) # error: (-215:Assertion failed) scn == m.cols || scn + 1 == m.cols in function 'transform'
```

The reason is the dimension of **each element** of `rotate_box` is `(2,)`. The transform by multiplication on matrices can not proceed.

**To another answer**:
As long as the last dimension fits, other dimensions do not matter. Continue the above snippet:

```
rotate_box_1 = np.array([rotate_box]) # 1x4x2
result_box = cv2.transform(rotate_box_1, rotation_mat) # 1x4x2

rotate_box_2 = np.array([[[410, 495]], [[756, 295]], [[956, 642]], [[610, 842]]]) # 4x1x2
result_box = cv2.transform(rotate_box_2, rotation_mat) # 4x1x2
```

**To reader**:
Note the shape returned by `cv2.transform()` is the same as the `src`.