# cv2.perspectiveTransform() not accepting homography matrix

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

Below are `bookhomography-example-1.jpg` and then `bookhomography-example-2.jpg` from a [popular OpenCV blogpost](http://www.learnopencv.com/homography-examples-using-opencv-python-c/) about homography.

I can do the homography and warp the image, but the `h` or `h[0]` do not work when I try to use `cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, h)` or `cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, h[0])`. I've also tried converting the 2D array `h[0]` to a tuple of tuples, but no change. It's probably something simple, but I can't figure it out.

> Error Message:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "bookhomography stackexchange v00.py", line 36, in  T_dst
>   = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts_dst, h) TypeError: m is not a numerical tuple

**note:** set `False` to `True` to induce failure. One of the two transform lines is the wrong direction but both fail.

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cv2

im_src = cv2.imread("bookhomography-example-2.jpg")
im_dst = cv2.imread("bookhomography-example-1.jpg")

im_srcrgb = cv2.cvtColor(im_src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
im_dstrgb = cv2.cvtColor(im_dst, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

pts_src = np.float32([52, 376, 240, 528, 413, 291, 217, 266]).reshape(4, -1)
pts_dst = np.float32([56, 478, 387, 497, 376, 124, 148, 218]).reshape(4, -1)

h       = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)

print "type(h): ", type(h)
print "len(h): ", len(h)

print "type(h[0]): ", type(h[0])
print "len(h[0]): ", len(h[0])
print "h[0].shape: ", h[0].shape

shape   = im_src.shape[:2][::-1]

print h[0]

print "pts_src:"
print pts_src

print "pts_dst:"
print pts_dst

if False:
    T_dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts_dst, h)
    T_src = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts_src, h)

    print "T_src:"
    print T_src

    print "T_dst:"
    print T_dst

im_fin  = cv2.warpPerspective(im_src, h[0], shape)
im_finrgb  = cv2.cvtColor(im_fin, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

plt.figure()
plt.subplot(1, 3, 1)
plt.imshow(im_srcrgb)
x, y = pts_src.T
plt.plot(x, y, 'or', ms=8)
plt.subplot(1, 3, 2)
plt.imshow(im_dstrgb)
x, y = pts_dst.T
plt.plot(x, y, 'or', ms=8)
plt.subplot(1, 3, 3)
plt.imshow(im_finrgb)
x, y = pts_dst.T
plt.plot(x, y, 'or', ms=8)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I thought there was a question: "I can do the homography and warp the image, but the `h` or `h[0]` do not work when I try to use `cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, h)` or `cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts, h[0])`." **note:** set `False` to `True` to induce failure.

Comment: There are different error messages for when you use `h` or `h[0]` in `perspectiveTransform()`, so you should include both of those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OpenCV Python cv2.perspectiveTransform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45817325/opencv-python-cv2-perspectivetransform)

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds OK I'll check that right now, and the other Question as well; give me about 10 more minutes, thanks!

Comment: No worries, I already answered. I was just letting you know :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45818765/5087436) for the quick fix. TL:DR; The OpenCV function `perspectiveTransform()` takes points specified in an odd format, whereas `findHomography()` works with the format you have.

---

First note that `findHomography()` returns *two* values; the homography matrix, and a `mask`. From the [docs](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findhomography):

> `cv2.findHomography(srcPoints, dstPoints[, method[, ransacReprojThreshold[, mask]]]) → retval, mask`

The second return value is not the homography, hence why `h[0]` should be used. Alternatively you could write:

```
h, mask = cv2.findHomography(srcPoints, dstPoints)
```

or

```
h = cv2.findHomography(srcPoints, dstPoints)[0]
```

so that `h` *only* holds the homography for less confusion. And note that using `h` or `h[0]` as you've specified gives you different error messages:

Using `h`:

```
>>> T_dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts_dst, h)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: m is not a numerical tuple
```

Using `h[0]`:

```
>>> T_dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts_dst, h[0])
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (scn + 1 == m.cols) in perspectiveTransform, file .../opencv/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 2299
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
cv2.error: .../opencv/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp:2299: error: (-215) scn + 1 == m.cols in function perspectiveTransform
```

The error messages are not really helpful to you here, unfortunately, because the actual problem is the way the points are specified. This is technically user error, but the docs (and the function itself) should probably be changed.

---

Anyways, the fix: add a channel to your `pts` vectors. See the difference:

```
>>> np.float32([52, 376, 240, 528, 413, 291, 217, 266]).reshape(4, -1)
array([[  52.,  376.],
       [ 240.,  528.],
       [ 413.,  291.],
       [ 217.,  266.]], dtype=float32)
>>> np.float32([52, 376, 240, 528, 413, 291, 217, 266]).reshape(4, 1, -1)
array([[[  52.,  376.]],

       [[ 240.,  528.]],

       [[ 413.,  291.]],

       [[ 217.,  266.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Luckily, `findHomography()` works with this format as well, so you don't have to use two different formats depending on which function you're using. To be safe, just always put points in this format for OpenCV functions.

```
>>> pts_src = np.float32([52, 376, 240, 528, 413, 291, 217, 266]).reshape(4, 1, -1)
>>> pts_dst = np.float32([56, 478, 387, 497, 376, 124, 148, 218]).reshape(4, 1, -1)
>>> h = cv2.findHomography(pts_src, pts_dst)[0]
>>> T_dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts_dst, h)
>>> T_src = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts_src, h)
>>> T_src
array([[[  56.,  478.]],

       [[ 387.,  497.]],

       [[ 376.,  124.]],

       [[ 148.,  218.]]], dtype=float32)
>>> T_dst
array([[[ 157.78089905,  588.9598999 ]],

       [[ 495.96539307,  365.68994141]],

       [[ 200.45231628,  -69.54611206]],

       [[  15.72697926,  204.0632019 ]]], dtype=float32)
```

The above produces no errors.

Comment: Yippee! OK I understand your explanation fully, thank you for taking the time to make it so clear. Indeed I get numbers now and the ones that should be correct are indeed correct - the back transformation works.

Comment: Do you think this should be duplicate of the other Q&A, or just leave as is?

Comment: Well, the problem and solution are a duplicate, but your title will likely come up more in searches. The community should decide, but the OpenCV tag doesn't have a lot of users, so we'll see if it will get stamped as a dupe or not.

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Questions marked as duplicates are not automatically deleted. They are left as duplicates for precisely the reason you give, so that more search terms will lead to the correct answer. I'll go ahead and suggest this as a duplicate of the question you linked.

Comment: That was puzzling the heck out of me just now and this is both the clearest answer I have found,  and one of the best examples for using both functions I found as well. (- Thanks!)      
I would strongly support keeping this answer _and_ moving at least some of it into the OpenCV Python doco/tutorials.