# How to convert a list of points to a matrix with datatype CV_32FC2 or vectr<Point2f)>?

Tags: python, opencv

I am using OpenCV 2.

At the moment I have a list of points: `[(1,2), (2,3), (3,4)]`

I need the points to be in a 3 x 1 matrix with datatype `CV_32FC2` or `vector<Point2f>`.

How do I do that?

Comment: It seems you are missing something here.... for what do you need such datatype? a function of OpenCV perhaps? knowing which one would help to give an accurate answer :) in python opencv Mats are numpy arrays. If you need 3x1 mat just create a 3x1 array, probably you need is 3xn actually

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Need help in understanding error for cv2.undistortPoints()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47402445/need-help-in-understanding-error-for-cv2-undistortpoints)

Answer (score 4):

See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47403282/5087436) for details on how OpenCV expects points in most functions and why.

The short answer is you need to convert your points to a *two-channel* array of 32-bit floats as the error states: `CV_32FC2`, i.e. a three-dimensional array with shape `(n_points, 1, 2)`.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> points = np.array([(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)])
>>> points = np.float32(points[:, np.newaxis, :])
>>> points
array([[[ 1.,  2.]],

       [[ 2.,  3.]],

       [[ 3.,  4.]]], dtype=float32)
```